# converting string from html into list

Tags: html, css, string, list, split

I'm trying to convert a string to a list, and I'd like to split it at line break.

The string from the html div looks like this:

```
[<div class="address-lg w-brk-ln-1 ">\r\n                \r\n                1010\r\n    \r\n    \r\n        Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt\r\n            </div>]
[<div class="address-lg w-brk-ln-1 ">\r\n                \r\n                1010\r\n    \r\n    \r\n        Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt\r\n            </div>]
[<div class="address-lg w-brk-ln-1 ">\r\n                \r\n                    Franz-Josefs-Kai 31,\r\n                \r\n                1010\r\n    \r\n    \r\n        Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt\r\n            </div>]
[<div class="address-lg w-brk-ln-1 ">\r\n                \r\n                1010\r\n    \r\n    \r\n        Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt\r\n            </div>]
...
```

What I'd like to have as a result is a list like:

```
[Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt, 1010, ]
[Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt, 1010, ]
[Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt, 1010, Franz-Josefs-Kai 31]
[Wien, 01. Bezirk, Innere Stadt, 1010, ]
...
```

My attempt to solve it until now was something like this:

```
address = result.select('div.bottom-content div.address-lg.w-brk-ln-1')[0].get_text().strip().replace("\r\n","").split()
address2 = list(reversed(address))
```

But what I get is always:

```
[u'Stadt', u'Innere', u'Bezirk,', u'01.', u'Wien,', u'1010']
[u'Stadt', u'Innere', u'Bezirk,', u'01.', u'Wien,', u'1010']
[u'Stadt', u'Innere', u'Bezirk,', u'01.', u'Wien,', u'1010', u'Sch\xf6nlaterngasse,']
```

Since it is unicode, I think in need to .encode() it, but also I need to split it at the right spot.

Comment: You did not specify what programming language you work with. Maybe adding this information to the tags is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are splitting by spaces but you should split by commas: `split(",")`. If you do so you may need to trim your results as they could contain lots of trailing spaces.

But as you did not specify any programming language, this is just a guess.